# Symfony2 how to create multi dimensional collection field

Tags: php, symfony

how can i create a multi dimensionnal collection field with symfony2 like this data format:

```
array [
   group_1=>[index_1=>value_1, index_2=value_2], 
   group_2=>[
             group_3=>[index_1=>value_1]
             index_1=value_1
            ]
  ]
```

my problem is how to represente this data forma in a form type like

```
public function buildForm ( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
{

    $fields = $this->form->getFieldset($fieldset->name);

    if ( !empty($fields) ) {

        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {

        $groups = explode('.', $field->group); // the result in the form should be like this fieldnamegroup[group1][group2]

        foreach ($groups as $group)
            {
                $builder->add($group, 'collection' array('type'=>"another collection type for making a cascade of subgroup" ));

            }

           $builder->add($field->__get('name'), new FieldType($field)); // final type


        }
    }
}
```

i want to create another form type Group extended of CollectionType but i read in the forums that not possible

the final result field that i need to show is like

```
<input name="FieldControl[Group1][Group2][Group3]" value = "value from the Field type object">
```

Comment: i delete my anser tkx for editing i am new and sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is php question:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);
```

Check php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).